# g++ en linux ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

Tengo una práctica con un ejemplo, esta es [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta que tengo es sobre el uso de -c en el comando de **g++ -c**, mi profesor me ha dicho que busque en internet su uso, pero llevo un rato buscando y ningún enlace me lleva a una solución.
Por ejemplo, quedaría igual la ejecución del código en el caso de que se hiciera **g++ "archivo"** solo?

Comment: Bienvenido  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: ¿Por que te mandan a buscar a Internet si tienes toda la información en tu propio equipo? en la terminal `man gcc`. Sino , esto mismo online: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html

Comment: Entiendo, gracias.

Comment: El problema reside en que mi profesor de software no es dedicado en lo más mínimo y la asignatura está costando hacerla por mi propia cuenta sin indicaciones.

Answer (score 0):

El proceso de compilación de C y C++ tiene varias fases. No entraré en detalle ya que no es el objetivo de la pregunta, pero de forma simplificada son 4:

- Preprocesado
- Compilación
- Ensamblado
- Enlazado

---

La [documentación oficial](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) dice:

> Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link. The linking stage simply is not done. The ultimate output is in the form of an object file for each source file.

Compila o ensambla los archivos de código fuente pero no los enlaza.

Básicamente, al usar la opción `-c` llega solo hasta la 3ª fase. El compilador genera un archivo `.o` que contiene instrucciones que el procesador puede entender, pero le falta pasar por la 4ª fase para ser un ejecutable completo.

Personalmente encuentro más cómodo hacer que el compilador genere el ejecutable final en un solo paso que tener que usar más comandos.

---

Links útiles:

- [Documentación de gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/).
- [Phases of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases).
- [4. Assembly Language & Computer Architecture](https://youtu.be/L1ung0wil9Y).
- [5. C to Assembly](https://youtu.be/wt7a5BOztuM).
- [C++ de The Cherno](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb)